# Error con ApplicationDbContext

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, office365

Actualmente estoy creando una aplicacion con la API de Graph y con acceso al `AD` en `ASP.NET`, todo funciona correctamente en modo debug, pero al tratar de publicarlo en un IIS o en Azure como WebApp, ocurre el error después de logearse con la cuenta de **O365** y redireccionar a mi página principal:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Eso pasa al tratar de generar el cache

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
//más código aquí
.
.
.
Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
```

El db se generó de una manera automática, así que no sé cómo funciona del todo bien:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20190809024809.mdf;User Instance=true;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication2-20190809024809;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Ya intenté añadir la instancia *MSSQLLocalDB* inclusive reemplazar (localdb) con v11.0, el np pipe, cambiar al nombre del servidor en un IIS y nada de esto funciona, sigue marcando el mismo error.

En el caso de Azure tengo entendido que no existe un localdb así que no sé cómo se tendría que modificar para que funcionara.

Answer (score 0):

espero poder ayudarte.
El problema es que este tipo de conexión:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20190809024809.mdf;User Instance=true;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication2-20190809024809;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

La puedes usar en tu entorno local para pruebas pero no cuando lo implementas.

Lo que debes hacer es conectarte a un servidor. La conexión debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=ip_o_nombre_del_servidor;Database=Nombre_de_la_base;User ID=usuario;Password=passdeejemplo123;Trusted_Connection=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

[[Server=ip_o_nombre_del_servidor]] debe ser "visible" desde donde implementas tu app.